# STM32 Nucleo-144

Tags: stm32

подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить работать плату STM32 Nucleo-144 работать как USB-Host?

Answer (score 0):

Заставлять не надо, достаточно залить нужную прошивку.

Библиотеки STM32Cube содержат примеры и демо на всю, поддерживаемую платой, периферию. Примеры реализации USB-хоста лежат в этой папке:

```
Projects\[Название вашей платы]\Applications\USB_Host
```

Примеры для плат типа Evaluation Board (EVAL) обычно побогаче - больше разных вариантов, но под другие платы их можно портировать (адаптировать под другое подключение периферии, распиновку процессора и т.п.).